# NSFileManager createFileAtPath failing on iPad but works on Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, createfile

I am trying to write a simple log file for each execution of my app.  The logfile name is based on the current time and is stored in the app directory.  The code below is what I am trying which works on the simulator but when I execute on an iPad it fails with 'Operation not permitted' (EPERM in errno.h).

```
-(BOOL)CreateLogFile
{
    mLogFilePath = [self GetLogFileNameForTimeNow];
    BOOL Success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:mLogFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];

    /*BOOL Success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:mLogFilePath contents:nil attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete
                                                                                                                                     forKey:NSFileProtectionKey]];*/

    if ( Success )
    {
        NSLog( @"Successfully created file: %@", mLogFilePath );
        mLogFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:mLogFilePath];
        [self WriteInstanceInformationToLog];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"Failed to create file: %@ %s", mLogFilePath, strerror(errno) );
    }

    return Success;
}
```

I tried the commented out code too but that also fails.  I am new to iOS programming so might be missing something basic.  Anyway the output form the above shows the following on iPad:

```
2013-05-10 14:54:51.794 RichTest1[128:907] Failed to create file:
/var/mobile/Applications/XXXX/RichTest1.app/20130510145451.log Operation not permitted
```

but on the simulator it works:

```
2013-05-10 15:07:14.696 RichTest1[1604:c07] Successfully created file:
Users/abruce/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/XXXX/RichTest1.app/20130510150714.log
```

Where am I going wrong?

--edit
Here is the code for the `GetLogFileNameForTimeNow`

```
-(NSString*)GetLogFileNameForTimeNow
{
    NSString* FileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.log", [self GetTimeAsString] ];
    NSString* AppFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", AppFolderPath, FileName];
}

-(NSString*)GetTimeAsString
{
    return [mDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

and the date formatter is setup as follows in the constructor of my class:

```
mDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString* DateFormat = @"yyyyMMddHHmmss";
[mDateFormatter setDateFormat:DateFormat];
```

Comment: Show your code for `GetLogFileNameForTimeNow`.

Comment: It was saving to the application folder, which I would add here but code isnt allowed in comments.  It now works by saving to the documents folder

Comment: Code is allowed in comments but the proper thing to do would be to edit your original question and add the additional code as an update.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the original question now

Answer (score 12):

You are trying to create a file inside app bundle, which is read-only on the device. Put your files into Documents or Library directories of the application.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I thought I would have permission to write to the app bundle directory but I guess not!

Answer (score 9):

**You are trying to create a file in a place where you don't have permissions to create files,**

Create your files inside documents folder,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"20130510150714.log"];
BOOL Success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem by changing my GetLogFileNameForTimeNow function as follows:

```
-(NSString*)GetLogFileNameForTimeNow
{
    NSString* FileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.log", [self GetTimeAsString] ];

    NSArray* Paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* DocumentsDirectory = [Paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", DocumentsDirectory, FileName];
}
```